# navigate to router link after clicking the button

Tags: angular

My clickme() method search shipment by id and if shipment is present i want to add routerlink to url/shipmentid. how do i solve this issue. currently i am displaying details below the serach

```
<p>
  <input type="text" id="id" name="id" [(ngModel)]="id" />
</p>
<button type="button" (click)="clickme()">Search by Id</button>
<div *ngIf="shipment">
  <div class="shipment">
    <p><span>Id:</span>{{ shipment.id }}</p>
    <p><span>Name:</span>{{ shipment.name }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

my ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShipmentService } from '../shipment.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shipment-search',
  templateUrl: './shipment-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shipment-search.component.css'],
})
export class ShipmentSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  shipment: any;

  constructor(private shipmentService: ShipmentService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  // searchShipment(): void {}
  id: string = '';
  clickme(): void {
    this.shipmentService.getShipment(this.id).subscribe((shipment) => {
      this.shipment = shipment;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following. After you verify the shipment ID redirect user to that page using Router instance as followed.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShipmentService } from '../shipment.service';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shipment-search',
  templateUrl: './shipment-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shipment-search.component.css'],
})
export class ShipmentSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  shipment: any;

  constructor(private shipmentService: ShipmentService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  // searchShipment(): void {}
  id: string = '';
  clickme(): void {
    this.shipmentService.getShipment(this.id).subscribe((shipment) => {
      this.shipment = shipment;
      this.router.navigate(['url/shipmentid']); // You routing path as argument
    });
  }
}
```